# Editing an array of strings in c

Tags: c, pointers, poker, arrayofstring

I'm writing code for a poker game and in my **main** function I have:

```
const char *suits[4] = { "Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds" };
const char *faces[13] = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

int deck[4][13] = { 0 };

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

char *hand[5] = { "\0" };

shuffle(deck);
deal(deck, faces, suits, hand);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%s", hand[i]);
}
```

This is where my general problem is. hand wont print out the values given to it in deal, which are 5 cards.

**shuffle()** simply shuffles the deck, no errors there so I am not going to include it in this question.

**deal()** has the following code (ignore the curly-bracket/whitespace discrepancies, I'm still adjusting to the formatting of this site):

```
void deal(const int wDeck[][13], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[], 
char *hand[]) {

int row = 0;    /* row number */
int column = 0; /*column number */
int card = 0;   /* card counter */

                /* deal 5 of the 52 cards */
for (card = 1; card <= 5; card++)
{
    /* loop through rows of wDeck */
    for (row = 0; row <= 3; row++)
    {
        /* loop through columns of wDeck for current row */
        for (column = 0; column <= 12; column++)
        {
            /* if slot contains current card, deal card */
            if (wDeck[row][column] == card)
            {
                char str1[10];
                strcpy(str1, wFace[column]);
                char str2[10];
                strcpy(str2, wSuit[row]);
                char str3[6] = " of ";
                char str[26] = "";
                strcat(str, str1);
                strcat(str, str3);
                strcat(str, str2);
                puts(str);

                hand[card - 1] = str;
                printf("%s\n", hand[card - 1]);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The code in the if statement works **just fine**.
The problem arises in **main()** when I try to print the values given to hand, however in **deal()** the values in hand print fine. I assume that I am not passing hand into the function correctly, but no matter the different methods I've tried to get the program to run correctly, nothing works.

An example of the program as is can be seen here:
[Example of program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsBKF.jpg)

Comment: So you're only showing the stuff that works and not the stuff that does not work? Please provide an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I provided the code that produces the issue at hand, and left out the irrelevant code that does not contribute to the problem.

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood then. But always include an MCVE. We should be able to more or less just copy your code to an editor and run it, and the problem should arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you `deal()` function:

```
hand[card - 1] = str;
```

`str` is local character array whose address will get invalidated once you return from `deal()`
right way to do it will be allocate memory to each element(max number of elements being 5) of `hand`, then copy value of `str` using `strcpy` into element of `hand`

e.g.

```
 hand[card - 1] = malloc(26);
 strcpy(hand[card - 1],str);
```